# How to use custom log4j properties for executors and drivers in Spark

Tags: java, logging, apache-spark, log4j, classpath

I am trying to setup custom log4j properties for Executor and Driver in Spark. I would like to do this without uploading the log4j file to the Executors and Driver nodes. I have log4j properties file in the application jar.

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties --class com.***.MainApp s3://**/**-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I don't have the log4j properties in the classpath. The manifest is as below:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: ###
Implementation-Version: 1.7
Implementation-Vendor: ###
```

And the structure of my jar is as below:

```
jar--
  ---- log4j.properties
  ---- com/
  ---- META-INF/
  ---- MANIFEST.MF
```

What changes do I need to make so that I can use the log4j.properties file present in the jar itself and don't need to upload it to the Executor and Driver nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `log4j.properties.template` available in `SPARK/conf` folder.

You can edit that log4j.properties file and place it in the same directory with your custom options.

Spark will take care of remaining. Since Spark internally uses log4j for logging.